# how to retrieve complex type object coming from webservice through ksoap SoapObject in android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, soap-client, android-ksoap2

I have a webservice that returns a complex object(say RouteDetails).when i am calling this webservice from my android code in which i have used ksoap library i am getting a response in soapobject but when i try to cast it to my complex object it throws classcast exception while when i print it on log it show me output like this -

" RuoteDetails{name="abc",id="2"} "

where RouteDetails is my object 
Now i am completely unaware of how to retrieve my object . Can any one please help. i hav gone through various links but couldnt find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ksoap2 can parse response into several types of objects.

1. `SoapObject` - the default one. You can use its methods `getProperty`, `getPropertySafely`, `getPropertyAsString` and so on for getting data. i.e
   `String value = response.getPropertySafelyAsString("propertyName", "default");`
2. Class which implements `KvmSerializable` interface and registered by [addMaping()](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapSerializationEnvelope.html#addMapping%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29).
3. Class which implements [Marshal](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/Marshal.html) interface and registered by [addMaping()](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapSerializationEnvelope.html#addMapping%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29).

In the last two cases you will get your object from `envelope.getResponse()` (in the first case your will get SoapObject).
So you can get your data from `SoapObject` or implement `KvmSerializable` or `Marshal` interfaces and register your class.

Comment: Thanks for reply now i am getting this new problem i am having a object that contains list of double....but in response i dont know why i am getting double{infinite=false; naN=false; }; as a ksoap response . Do you have any idea?? Please help